# How to drag a child according to mouse position in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a big draggable map to see all places on map. But I want to be able to drag it according to the mouse position.

How to drag a child according to mouse position in Jquery?

Here is my dragging code:

```
$(".map").draggable({
containment:[(parseInt($(".hk").width()) - parseInt($(".hkc").width())) * -1, 
(parseInt($(".hk").height()) - parseInt($(".hkc").height())) * -1, 0, 0], 
cursor: "move"
})
```

My demo is [here](http://shoutkey.com/pigtail)

and here is screenshot:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice pictures but they are pretty much worthless without seeing your DOM. Suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @charlietfl Here is my demo http://shoutkey.com/pigtail

Comment: not clear how to use demo to show problem in images

Comment: I need to be able click one white point and when I move my cursor to any place (what I cant see), my map should drag to that way. But I couldn't figure it out how to do that.

Comment: seems like you need to do something like bind `mousemove` handler to `mousedown` and adjust CSS position accordingly. Then on `mouseup` unbind the mousemove handler

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Variables for current position
var x, y;

function handleMouse(e) {
  // Verify that x and y already have some value
  if (x && y) {
    // Scroll window by difference between current and previous positions
    window.scrollBy(e.clientX - x, e.clientY - y);
  }

  // Store current position
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
}

// Assign handleMouse to mouse movement events
document.onmousemove = handleMouse;
```